# Symfony entity persist null

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a regular formType with some non-required, nullable elements like so :

```
->add('mytime', TimeType::class, array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    "required" => false
))
```

In the entity :

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mytime", type="time", nullable=true)
 */
private $mytime = null;
```

If I'm not defining it when inserting a new record, it works - it's a `NULL`. But if I do define it and later try to remove it by updating the form, it doesn't update and keeps it's value.

In the `isValid()` block I checked :

```
$data = $editForm->all();
print_r($data['mytime']->getData());
```

And it's actually empty. Same in the entity :

```
$entity->getMyTime()
```

is empty. But when I

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

`mytime` still has its old value.

What am I missing ?

[EDIT] as requested, full controller code :

```
public function myFunctionAction(Request $request ,$id, $to) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository(Day::class)->find($id);

    $editForm =  $this->createForm(new DayType(), $entity);
    $editForm->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'to'          => $to,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

[EDIT2]
After some tests with the ideas I got from the answers, I tried this in the `isValid()` section :

```
if(is_null($entity->getMyTime()) || empty($entity->getMyTime()))
    $entity->SetMyTime((new \DateTime())->setTime(00, 00));
```

So, it sets the time to 00, and I could potentially use that... BUT :
- The page when reloaded still shows the old value. It's normal, I think, since `$editForm` is declared before `isValid()` check (obviously) and not updated.
- Itls far from being ideal since storing 00:00 in the DB is a lot less relevant than a NULL.

Comment: Can you show your full code where you create the entity and set the time, up until you persist and flush it?

Comment: @AlvinBunk edited with controller code, is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Do you have the setter method in your entity called setMytime(), with M uppercased? It seems like the form field is not mapped to the entity. See also the Symfony profiler in the form section, in the dev environment.

Comment: @ste thanks, but no, I checked and the form field is correctly mapped to the entity... Otherwise it wouldn't update when I set another value into it, and it does. The only case where it does nothing is when I empty it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
    if(is_null($entity->getmytime()) || empty($entity->getmytime())) {
        $entity->setMytime(null);
    }
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I think the above code might work. Try it. Hope it works.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: if(is_null($entity->getmytime()) || empty($entity->getmytime())) {
    var_dump($entity);exit;
    $entity->setMytime(null);
}

Can you please check and post the output of above lines ?

Comment: I just want to see what mytime contains and if block is being executed or not.

Comment: It does work, I had to tweak minor things but in the end it's good ! Block ran, simply the form didn't update in the view, JS was faulty... Cound you explain why detecting that entity is `null` and then setting it to... `null` works ?!

Comment: I do not remember the concept exactly, because I left Symfony since last 10 months, but I answered as per my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try (second edit) this:

```
...
$editForm->get('mytime')->setData(new \DateTime());
...
if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I think that is the right code. Currently in your posted code, you don't do anything with the form or Entity, so nothing has changed. You need to do something with the form or entity, and then persist and flush it to see anything in the database.

The above code might not work, but give it a try, hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Error 500 - You cannot change the data of a submitted form !

Comment: You are setting the data in the form field, not in the entity

Comment: @mdma, the code is correct. I made an error in that it needs to be set before the call to submit. Set the same example in the [Creating Form Classes in Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes). Definitely doesn't deserve a -1 because the code should work.